# How to change button colour when active on React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here I have created the buttons that have an onclick event

```
<div className="OptionsRow">
                        <button className="OptionButton one" value="1" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Slow</button>
                        <button className="OptionButton two" value="2" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Medium</button>
                        <button className="OptionButton three" value="3" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Fast</button>
                        <button className="OptionButton four" value="4" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Medium-Slow</button>
                        <button className="OptionButton five" value="5" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Slow-Very Fast</button>
                    </div>
```

Here is the function the onClick event calls

```
function changeTimeLine(value){


  
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/growth-rate/'+value+'/') //growth rate
    .then((res)=>{

      
      let data=res.data;

      for(let i=0; i<data.levels.length;i++){

        experience.push(data.levels[i].experience);
        level.push(data.levels[i].level);


      };

      setUpdateExperience(experience);
      setUpdateLevel(level);

     

    })
     
    
}
```

I have created a group of buttons that update my API call when clicked. I want these buttons to change colour when that button is active.

Comment: Ok, you'll want to have a state variable, and then based on that state variable you set the className and/or style props of the button. If you want more information, please show us the code you have so far and point out where you're having a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a new state for an active button check

```
const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState()
```

And then use that `activeButton` for adding `active` class

```
<div className="OptionsRow">
                        <button className={`OptionButton one ${activeButton === "1" && "active"}`} value="1" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Slow</button>
                        <button className={`OptionButton two ${activeButton  === "2" && "active"}`} value="2" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Medium</button>
                        <button className={`OptionButton three ${activeButton  === "3" && "active"}`} value="3" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Fast</button>
                        <button className={`OptionButton four ${activeButton  === "4" && "active"}`} value="4" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Medium-Slow</button>
                        <button className={`OptionButton five ${activeButton === "5" && "active"}`} value="5" onClick={e => changeTimeLine(e.target.value)}>Slow-Very Fast</button>
                    </div>
```

You also need to have styles for `active` class

```
.OptionButton.active{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The last part is modifying your click event

```
function changeTimeLine(value){
    setActiveButton(value) //update your current active button state 
   
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/growth-rate/'+value+'/') //growth rate
    .then((res)=>{
      let data=res.data;
      for(let i=0; i<data.levels.length;i++){
        experience.push(data.levels[i].experience);
        level.push(data.levels[i].level);
      };
      setUpdateExperience(experience);
      setUpdateLevel(level);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To just change color of an active button, define your css class with something like this:

```
.OptionButton{
    background-color: 'white';
}
.OptionButton:active{
    background-color: 'blue';
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. However, I would like the button to remain active while that buttons contents shows.

Comment: Ah, cool - then it looks like the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71845067/16806458) is right for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
className={active ? "tabs-button active" : "tabs-button deactive"}
```

So basically it gives it a class of active and tabs-button when the button is active, and if it is not active it will give it a class of deactive and tabs-button.

Hope this helps or gives you an idea on how to accomplish your goal.